# jQuery Get all checked checkboxes with name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Im trying to get all checked boxes with a name if images[].

I would usually

```
 imgs = $('input:checkbox[name=images]:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

The below code is what I have tried and isnt working.

```
 imgs = $('input:checkbox[name=images[]]:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should escape the brackets (adding quotes would also avoid the problem, but escaping special characters is still good practice):

```
imgs = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="images\\[\\]"]:checked').map(function() { return this.value; }).get();
```

Comment: I tested and it worked, however I decided that there was no need to use the brackets so to make my code cleaner I removed them.

Comment: The brackets are only needed if you submit the form and need the values in an array, then the brackets will create an array on the serverside for you-

Comment: even without the brackets it is collected as an array, the jQuery searches all that is selected with that name and creates an new array to post. So it wasn't needed the way. Although I did use your solution and that had worked too :)